# Group tasks together in order

Tags: mysql

I'm going to use an analogy for this one, just to simplify the explanation.

Suppose in a game you have a building that can produce Archers and Cavalry. You place an order for 5 Archers, followed by 3 Cavalry, then place another order for a further 4 Archers.

For this example I have a MySQL table with:

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`buildingid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
`unit` ENUM('Archer','Cavalry') NOT NULL
`complete` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Now I want to display the units in the order queue. Most games of this style will simply display the 5 Archers, 3 Cavalry, and 4 other Archers in a line. But since I don't want a limit on the length of the queue, this could be very messy for bigger orders (say, 200 Archers)

I'd like to be able to have MySQL return `buildingid, unit, count, next`, where "count" is the number of units and "next" is the timestamp of the earliest unit that will be completed.

While I could use a `GROUP BY` query, this would group all the Archers together regardless of the Cavalry in between. I'd need a way of grouping by unit type, limited to consecutive entries.

My previous attempt at this worked, but completely crashed the server when I tested ordering 1000 units.

I hope I explained what I'm trying to do clearly enough...

Comment: Post your previous query. You probably just need to add some indexes.

Comment: Well, when I tried it before it was about a year ago, and the code is so bad that looking at it now I can't understand what I was thinking... But the general idea was "get the task with lowest ID, then get the first task that's not the same", repeated until the end was reached... Or something. Wow, my coding sucked a year ago o_O

Comment: But yes, at the time I didn't know about Indexes, so that's probably the sole cause for problems!

Comment: Doubtful it's only indexes, there's still a lot of things that can cause a [full table scan](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/), which can be the pain point. It can actually even be vice versa, so testing is required.

Comment: Given that back then I didn't even have a Primary Key on the ID field, I think Indexes would certainly go a long way to making it work better. I'll see what I can come up with, when I eventually get time to pick this project up again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to group them in the database by adding a "quantity" field. When the time is reached, reduce the quantity by one and reset the timer for the next one's completion time, or delete the row if the quantity is zero.